# R: gather gives warning when using vector variable to select columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm using the gather command in R to collapse a data frame and it gives a warning that's not clear to me. The command does what it's supposed to do but I'd like to understand the reason for the warning. It's a new warning, may be related to updating the R install and packages recently.

I recreated the problem in a simple example with the iris data, see below, it works with no warning with column numbers 2,3 but gives the warning if I use a vector I create as tt:

```
> head(gather(iris,key=test,value=nn,2,3),2)
    Sepal.Length Petal.Width   Species         test  nn
299          6.2         2.3 virginica Petal.Length 5.4
300          5.9         1.8 virginica Petal.Length 5.1
> tt<- c(2,3)
> head(gather(iris,key=test,value=nn,tt),2)
    Sepal.Length Petal.Width   Species         test  nn
299          6.2         2.3 virginica Petal.Length 5.4
300          5.9         1.8 virginica Petal.Length 5.1
Warning message:
In if (!is.finite(x)) return(FALSE) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Thanks, Claudiu

Comment: Can u show the versions of dplyr/tidyr as both of them gives me error

Comment: tidyr version is 0.7.2 and dplyr 0.7.4. The relevant one for gather afaik is tidyr

Comment: Yes, I do have the same versions, but unfortunately both are ending up in error. i.e. `last(gather(iris,key=test,value=nn,2,3),2)#
Error in order(order_by)[[n]] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: try head instead of last and if it works for you let me know an I'll edit the question. The last command may come from quantmod

Comment: That is the key, now it is working

Comment: thanks for finding this. Now if you could help also with the problem of the warning...:-)

Comment: Try with `names` ie. `last(gather(iris,key=test,value=nn, names(iris)[tt]),2)`

Comment: Works. Do you understand why 2,3 works but tt<-c(2,3) does not? Anyway, why don't you put your solution as an answer, it does the job.

Comment: Based on the type of error, it could be a bug.  I would recommend to use name based instead of position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to have `names` instead of position because position may change when a column is deleted or added.  As 'tt' is a numeric index, we can use that to subset the column names

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(quantmod)
last(gather(iris,key=test,value=nn, names(iris)[tt]),2)
#    Sepal.Length Petal.Width   Species         test  nn
#299          6.2         2.3 virginica Petal.Length 5.4
#300          5.9         1.8 virginica Petal.Length 5.1
```

Comment: @claudiu  Thanks, I didn't copy the code correctly.